# background image not responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As the title says, my background image isn't responsive. I have applied to class "img-responsive" to my page header. However the image isn't shrinking with the page. Any Ideas?

```
<div class="jumbotron">
   <div class="page-header" class="img-responsive">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.page-header {

  margin-right: 70px;
  background-image: url("../img/test.png");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position:center;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 700px;
  margin-left: 333px;

}
```

Comment: `.img-responsive` is for `img`s. The fixed height/width on `.page-header` is keeping that element from being responsive. Use a relative width/height or media queries.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Relative width/height?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp "There are two types of length units: relative and absolute". A fixed unit (like px) is an absolute.

Comment: since other people answered, do you want this as an answer? I was just going to leave a comment but can answer if you think it's helpful and solves the problem.

Comment: Sure! It was the % which was the problem.

Comment: I had it in px as explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.img-responsive` is for `img`s, not normal elements. The fixed height/width on `.page-header` is keeping that element from being responsive. If you want that element to be responsive (and then the background will be responsive because you're using a responsive `background-size`), then use relative units (%, em, rem, vh, vw, etc) on `.page-header` instead of fixed (px) units, or use some `@media` queries.

Answer (score 2):

Use `background-size:cover;` and then as long as you have `max-width:100%;` set on the container, it will resize once you get below 700px. Also, there's no need for the `img-responsive` class since that's for `img` elements.

```css
.page-header {
  background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position:center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 700px;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
   <div class="page-header"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply the width and height as a percent of window width.  Let's say you want 700px `width` if window width is 1000px then write

```
width: 70%;
```